# PHP - Form not saving data to POST

Tags: php

So I encountered a weird problem with my form. When I click the oplsaan button it does not run through the code in **if(isset($_POST['opslaan']))**. The thing is that PHP doesn't save the form data to the $_POST array. For example, when I click opslaan in the following form:

```
    if(isset($_POST['wijzigen']))
    {
                    $query_selecteren = 'SELECT *
                                        FROM contacten';

                    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query_selecteren);

                    echo '<form id="wijzigingscherm" method="post" action="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '">';
                        echo '<table>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Keuze</th>
                                <th>Afbeelding</th>
                                <th>Voornaam</th>
                                <th>Achternaam</th>
                                <th>Woonplaats</th>
                                <th>Telefoonnummer</th>
                                <th>Adres</th>
                                <th>Postcode</th>
                                <th>Opmerking</th>
                            </tr>';
                            foreach ($result as $rij) {
                                echo '<tr>';
                                    $rijnr%2==0 ? $rijkleur='#6B9ED1' : $rijkleur='#99B3CC';
                                    echo '<td style="background-color'  . $rijkleur .'"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkedUser" value="' . $rij['contact_id'] . '"/>';
                                    echo '<td style="background-color'.$rijkleur.'"> <img src="ImgPersonen/profiel.jpg"/>';
                                    echo '<td style="background-color:' . $rijkleur .'"> <input size="7" type="text" name="voornaam" placeholder="' . $rij['vnaam'] .'"/></td>';
                                    echo '<td style="background-color:' . $rijkleur .'"> <input size="7" type="text" name="achternaam" placeholder="' . $rij['anaam'] . '"</td>';
                                    echo '<td style="background-color:' . $rijkleur .'"> <input size="7" type="text" name="woonplaats" placeholder="' . $rij['wplaats'] . '"/></td>';
                                    echo '<td style="background-color:' . $rijkleur .'"> <input size="7" type="text" name="telefoonnummer" placeholder="' . $rij['tnummer'] . '"/></td>';
                                    echo '<td style="background-color:' . $rijkleur .'"> <input size="7" type="text" name="adres" placeholder="' . $rij['adres'] . '"/></td>';
                                    echo '<td style="background-color:' . $rijkleur . '"> <input size="7" type="text" name="postcode" placeholder="' . $rij['postcode'] . '"/></td>';
                                    echo '<td style="background-color:' . $rijkleur . '"> <input size="7" type="text" name="opmerking" placeholder="' . $rij['opmerking'] . '"/></td>';
                                    $rijnr++;
                                echo '</tr>';
                            }
                        echo '</table>
                        <input type="submit" name="opslaan" style="width:15%;" value="Opslaan" />
                        <input type="submit" name="annuleren" style="width:15%;" value="Annuleren" />
                    </form>';
    }
```

It should run this code which I placed under session_start

```
if(isset($_POST['opslaan']))
{
    $query_opslaan = 'a query using the post data';

    mysqli_query($link, $query_opslaan) or die(mysqli_error($query_opslaan));                       

    header('location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}
```

but the weird thing is that the if(isset($_POST['osplaan'])) doesn't work for some reason and I really don't know what I'm doing wrong here! Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What do you see from `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: Just Array ( ) and nothing else

Answer (score 1):

One of your Inputs Fields wasn't properly closed: **achternaam** and thus it might present some really unexpected results. Below is what you might want to try, instead and by the way; your Form Tag should be nested within the Loop for this to work:

**THE FORM PART**

```
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['wijzigen'])) {
            $query_selecteren = 'SELECT *
                                                FROM contacten';

            $result = mysqli_query($link, $query_selecteren);
            $count  = 1;

            echo '<table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Keuze</th>
                                        <th>Afbeelding</th>
                                        <th>Voornaam</th>
                                        <th>Achternaam</th>
                                        <th>Woonplaats</th>
                                        <th>Telefoonnummer</th>
                                        <th>Adres</th>
                                        <th>Postcode</th>
                                        <th>Opmerking</th>
                                        <th>Edits</th>
                                    </tr>';
            foreach ($result as $rij) {
                echo '<form id="wijzigingscherm" method="post" action="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '">';
                echo '<tr>';
                $rijkleur = ($rijnr%2==0) ? '#6B9ED1' : '#99B3CC';
                echo '<td style="background-color'  . $rijkleur .'"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkedUser" value="'                 . $rij['contact_id']    . '"/>';
                echo '<td style="background-color'  .$rijkleur.'"> <img src="ImgPersonen/profiel.jpg"/>';
                echo '<td style="background-color:' . $rijkleur .'"> <input size="7" type="text" name="voornaam" placeholder="'         . $rij['vnaam']         . '" value="' . $rij['vnaam']       . '" /></td>';
                echo '<td style="background-color:' . $rijkleur .'"> <input size="7" type="text" name="achternaam" placeholder="'       . $rij['anaam']         . '" value="' . $rij['anaam']       . '" /></td>';
                echo '<td style="background-color:' . $rijkleur .'"> <input size="7" type="text" name="woonplaats" placeholder="'       . $rij['wplaats']       . '" value="' . $rij['wplaats']     . '" /></td>';
                echo '<td style="background-color:' . $rijkleur .'"> <input size="7" type="text" name="telefoonnummer" placeholder="'   . $rij['tnummer']       . '" value="' . $rij['tnummer']     . '" /></td>';
                echo '<td style="background-color:' . $rijkleur .'"> <input size="7" type="text" name="adres" placeholder="'            . $rij['adres']         . '" value="' . $rij['adres']       . '" /></td>';
                echo '<td style="background-color:' . $rijkleur . '"> <input size="7" type="text" name="postcode" placeholder="'        . $rij['postcode']      . '" value="' . $rij['postcode']    . '" /></td>';
                echo '<td style="background-color:' . $rijkleur . '"> <input size="7" type="text" name="opmerking" placeholder="'       . $rij['opmerking']     . '" value="' . $rij['opmerking']   . '" /></td>';
                echo '<td style="">
                <input type="submit" name="opslaan" style="width:15%;"      value="Opslaan" /><br />
                <input type="reset" name="annuleren" style="width:15%;"     value="Annuleren" /><br/>
                </tr>;
            </form>';
                $rijnr++;
                $count++;


            }
            echo '</table>';
        }
```

**THE PROCESSING PART**

```
        if(isset($_POST['opslaan'])){
                //THIS IS WHERE AND WHEN YOU GATHER THE POSTED DATA FROM THE FORM...
                $voorname           = isset($_POST['voorname'])         ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['voorname']))        : null;
                $achternaam         = isset($_POST['achternaam'])       ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['achternaam']))      : null;
                $woonplaats         = isset($_POST['woonplaats'])       ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['woonplaats']))      : null;
                $telefoonnummer     = isset($_POST['telefoonnummer'])   ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['telefoonnummer']))  : null;
                $adres              = isset($_POST['adres'])            ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['adres']))           : null;
                $postcode           = isset($_POST['postcode'])         ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['postcode']))        : null;
                $opmerking          = isset($_POST['opmerking'])        ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['opmerking']))       : null;

                // NOW YOU CAN USE THE ABOVE VARIABLES IN YOUR QUERY, SHOULD YOU NEED TO...
                $query_opslaan      = 'a query using the post data';
                mysqli_query($link, $query_opslaan) or die(mysqli_error($query_opslaan));
                header('location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
        }
```

Comment: The query gets executed in the opslaan fucntion but the data from $_POST['voorname'] etc. still has no value

Comment: @B.Hulshof  Check with the part that reads `if(isset($_POST['wijzigen'])) {`. No one but you can tell if $results contains some data... `foreach ($result as $rij) {` may be another area to check. It is suggested to first do a var_dump after `$result = mysqli_query($link, $query_selecteren); var_dump($result); exit;` to see what you get...

Comment: the foreach loop contains data. I know this because it get's used as placeholder

Comment: @B. Hulshof    Nice you mentioned that. You actually solved the problem yourself. I will update the post right now....

Comment: We are close, there seems to be some trouble with contact_id. The checkbox seems to get the contact_id from the next contact. For example: I have contact 1 and 2. When I check contact 1 and type in data and hit save, it saves the data from contact 2 to contact 1, this should not happen.

Comment: @B.Hulshof     You have a table row in a Loop and all the input fields in each Row have the same name. It is clear that the last the values from the last rows will override those of the previous ones. To solve this problem, try to add a suffix to the names: perhaps using a counter as shown in the updated code...

Comment: But you only count with the counter and nothing more. How do I use this as suffix?

Comment: @B.Hulshof it is already there in the Code as part of the name of the input field. Example: `name="voornaam_' . $count . '"`  Notice the variable $count appended to voornaam? But now your processing would be very much different because the names of the Fields would change with this approach. In this case you need to loop through $_POST to extract the values of each Field.

Comment: @B.Hulshof     Just spotted the issue: Your opening Form Tag should be within the Foreach Loop for your code to work... Didn't notice that earlier. The Code has been updated... Give it a shot one more time...

Comment: Form in the foreach loop is a bad idea.

Comment: @B. Hulshof   Not if you prefer a little more simplicity over complexity... The idea might be unconventional but still think about it: if your loop has 20 Records, each of successive row will override the preceding one & even if you gave each field a unique name it would still be complex to extract the values. But, having a form within each row, the fields in each row can have the same names but the button associated with that Row only submits the fields-values of that row alone. However, the design of your Application is 100% up to you, though...